# how to fix simple slider bug - javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to create a simple slider using javascipt. the problem is when counter gets to last element, It dosen't change the display to block
this is the code

```
<div id="slider">
<img class="slide" src="img/img13.jpg" alt=""/>
<img class="slide" src="img/img14.jpg" alt=""/>
<img class="slide" src="img/img15.jpg" alt=""/>
<img class="slide" src="img/img16.jpg" alt=""/>
<img class="slide" src="img/img17.jpg" alt=""/>
<img class="slide" src="img/img18.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>

 var delay = 3000;
var i = 0;
var allSliderSlides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
allSliderSlides[0].style.display = "block";
setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    allSliderSlides[i].style.display = "block";

    if(allSliderSlides[i-1].style.display=="block"){
        allSliderSlides[i-1].style.display="none";
    }

    if(i == allSliderSlides.length-1){

        i = 0;
        allSliderSlides[allSliderSlides.length-1].style.display = "none";
        allSliderSlides[i].style.display = "block";


    }

},delay);
```

please give me some advice or suggestion to fix this problem
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You reassigned i = 0 before your last element to become block

Try:

```
if(i == allSliderSlides.length-1){

    allSliderSlides[allSliderSlides.length-1].style.display = "none";
    allSliderSlides[i].style.display = "block";
    i = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
if(i == allSliderSlides.length-1){

        i = 0;
        allSliderSlides[allSliderSlides.length-1].style.display = "none";
        allSliderSlides[i].style.display = "block";


    }
```

You are resetting the counter before changing the style. This results to displaying the fist image and the last image would never be displayed.

Solution: Move `i = 0;` to last line in the block like so:

```
    if(i == allSliderSlides.length-1){


                allSliderSlides[allSliderSlides.length-1].style.display = "none";
                allSliderSlides[i].style.display = "block";
                i = 0;


            }
```

Hope that helps.